# Edit and Continue doesn't work with Roslyn compiled class library

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, roslyn

**Background**

I'm trying to get Edit and Continue to work with a class library I'm compiling at runtime using Roslyn. This is for adding modding support to a game I'm developing.

---

**Breakdown of problem**

- I have one class library project (A) with source files (.cs)
- I have another console application project (B) in another solution that does the following:

  1. Compiles all of project A's source files
  2. Emits a dll and pdb
  3. Loads the emitted dll and pdb via an assembly context
  4. Calls a static method defined within project B
- My desire is to be able to attach a debugger to a running process of project B in an instance of VS with project A loaded and be able to break, edit project A's code, and continue with my changes being executed
- Currently, I am only able to break and continue
- Any edits lead to the following notification:

> This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the file used to build the application being debugged.

---

**Source**

Project A: *DebuggableClassLibrary.csproj*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Project A: *Test.cs*

```cs
using System;

namespace DebuggableClassLibrary
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static int Ct = 0;
        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Ct++;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Project B: *DynamicLoading.csproj*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="3.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project B: *Program.cs*

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Text;

namespace DynamicLoading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var references = new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("System.Runtime").Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location)
            };
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\mrbri\source\repos\DebuggableClassLibrary\DebuggableClassLibrary", "*.cs");
            var assemblyName = "DebuggableClassLibrary.dll";
            var debug = true;
            var allowUnsafe = false;
            var outputDirectory = @"C:\Users\mrbri\Documents\Test";
            
            var preprocessorSymbols = debug ? new string[] { "DEBUG" } : new string[] { };
            var parseOptions = new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.Latest, preprocessorSymbols: preprocessorSymbols);
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName: assemblyName,
                syntaxTrees: files.Select(f => SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(File.ReadAllText(f), parseOptions, f, Encoding.UTF8)), 
                references: references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(
                    OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                    assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default,
                    optimizationLevel: debug ? OptimizationLevel.Debug : OptimizationLevel.Release,
                    allowUnsafe: allowUnsafe
                ));

            var pePath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, assemblyName);
            var pdbPath = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, Path.ChangeExtension(assemblyName, ".pdb"));

            using (var peStream = new FileStream(pePath, FileMode.Create))
            using (var pdbStream = new FileStream(pdbPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var results = compilation.Emit(
                    peStream: peStream, 
                    pdbStream: pdbStream, 
                    options: new EmitOptions(debugInformationFormat: DebugInformationFormat.PortablePdb)
                    );
            }
            
            var assemblyLoadContext = new SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext();
            var assembly = assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromStream(File.OpenRead(pePath), File.OpenRead(pdbPath));
            var type = assembly.GetTypes().First();
            var method = type.GetMethod("SayHello");

            while (true)
            {
                method.Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        public SimpleUnloadableAssemblyLoadContext(): base(true) { }
        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName) => null;
    }
}
```

---

**Attempts at solutions and observations**

- Compiling project A manually through VS and loading the generated pdb and dll exactly as I do for the Roslyn compiled one does allow for Edit and Continue
- Comparing project A's dlls generated via Roslyn and VS in JetBrains dotPeek did yield some interesting differences that stem from the compilation time generated `.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs` and `DebuggableClassLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs` that I do not include when I compile in project B
- Going through the trouble of compiling project A via a MSBuildWorkspace Project did not allow Edit and Continue, although did include `.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs` and `DebuggableClassLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs`

---

**Alternatives**

I am open to Roslyn alternatives/wrappers that do have Edit and Continue support.

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Continue does not support this scenario. The project for the library being edited needs to be loaded in VS (in the current solution) and the program needs to be launched with the debugger attached.